# What is the best way to do this array tranformation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have an initial object. Context can have more than 2 keys.

```
 {
  term: 'account',
  definition: 'term definition',
  context: 'defaultValues.accountNames'
 },
 {
  term: 'position',
  definition: 'position definition',
  context: 'defaultValues.accountNames'
 },
```

And I need to format it to next (context and term - keys of object, and term is the last prop and have a definition value)

```
{
  defaultValues: {
    accountNames: {
      account: "term definition",
      position: "position definition"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://www.google.com/search?q=js+array+reduce&rlz=1C1GCEB_enCA934CA934&oq=js+array+red&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0l8.1989j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

```js
let arr = [{
  term: 'account',
  definition: 'term definition',
  context: 'defaultValues.accountNames'
 },
 {
  term: 'position',
  definition: 'position definition',
  context: 'defaultValues.accountNames'
}]
let res = arr.reduce((acc, {term, definition, context})=>{
    context.split('.').reduce((a,b)=>(a[b] ??= {}), acc)[term] = definition;
    return acc;
}, {});
console.log(res);
```